# Symfony load joined entities with where and order by

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine-orm, repository, dql

I have two entities, first called `Page`, second one `PageEntry`

The PageEntries are mapped in `Page` by:

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|PageEntry[]
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PageEntry")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="foobar_page_to_entries")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"position" = "ASC"})
 */
private $entries;
```

I tried now to have a function in the `PageRepository` to load all the joined `PageEntry` with the condition `hide = false` and sorted by `position ASC`

To do so, I created this function:

```
public function getEntriesByPage(Page $page = null) {
    if (empty($page)) {
        return array();
    }

    $query = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('e')
            ->from('FooBarBundle:Page', 'p')
            ->andWhere('p.id = :id')
            ->join('p.entries', 'e')
            ->andWhere('e.hide = :hide')
            ->addOrderBy('e.position', 'ASC')

            ->setParameters(array(
                'hide'  => false,
                'id'    => $page->getId()
            ))
    ;

    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Which results in a `Semantical Error`:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col -1 near 'SELECT e FROM': Error: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias.

What can I do, to fix this? Or is there a better way? (I tried to use `Criteria` but the version of Doctrine is a little outdated and tells me, that Criteria does only work on `OneToMany` relations).

Answer (score 0):

change your query like this one and try it. let me know if any issue.

```
$query = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('e')
            ->from('FooBarBundle:Page', 'p')
            ->join('p.entries', 'e')
             ->Where('p.id = :id')
            ->andWhere('e.hide = :hide')
            ->OrderBy('e.position', 'ASC')

            ->setParameters(array(
                'hide'  => false,
                'id'    => $page->getId()
            ))
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the root alias `'p'` to your select statement for this query to work:

```
$query = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('p', 'e')
    ->from('FooBarBundle:Page', 'p')
    ->andWhere('p.id = :id')
    ->join('p.entries', 'e')
    ->andWhere('e.hide = :hide')
    ->addOrderBy('e.position', 'ASC')

    ->setParameters(array(
        'hide'  => false,
        'id'    => $page->getId()
    ));
```

Since you are in your `PageRepository` you can do more simple like this:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->addSelect('e')
    ->andWhere('p.id = :id')
    ->join('p.entries', 'e')
    ->andWhere('e.hide = :hide')
    ->addOrderBy('e.position', 'ASC')
```

`from` is not necessary if you are already in the correct entity repository. You can just pass the alias for the entity (in this case `'p'`) directly to the `createQueryBuilder` method and skip the `from` part.